# Add a text string before and after any value in a text string appears in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Question!

I have a few hundred cells with text strings that also contain numbers within them. I want with a formula to add text before and after each presence of a number.

So for example: "Find 2 dogs, 3 times". I'd want to turn this to

*"Find [insertedtextbefore]2[insertedtextafter] dogs', [insertedtextbefore]3[insertedtextafter] times".*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- You want to put `[insertedtextbefore]` to before the number in the text of the cell.
- You want to put `[insertedtextafter]` to after the number in the text of the cell.
- As a sample value, you want to achieve as follows.

  - From

    ```
    Find 2 dogs, 3 times
    ```
  - To

    ```
    Find [insertedtextbefore]2[insertedtextafter] dogs, [insertedtextbefore]3[insertedtextafter] times
    ```
- You want to achieve this using the built-in functions of Google Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A5," (\d+) ", " [insertedtextbefore]$1[insertedtextafter] "))
```

- In this case, the values are put to the cells "A1:A5".

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.